# multi level nested JSON output using PHP through MySQL and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I'm trying to create a JSON output for a PHP website project. I have done quite a bit of research that ended up completely confusing me in the end.

First of, I'm not sure what would be best between PDO or mysqli but I had to move forward and go with PDO. I understand the process of connecting to the server - selecting the database and table. I'm sturggling with outputing the data in the actual nested JSON format that I so cafully planned.

While I am not 100% sure I got it all right 
I think I just need to keep doing it with the right code 
until everythy makes sense...

Please help!

I am looking to get to somthing like this for my JSON output:

```
maincategory = {
    "subcategory1" : {
        "group" : {
            "subgroup" :{
                "name" : "Jason Lengstorf",
                "age" : "24","gender" : "male",
                "height" : "6.3",
                "weight" : "164lbs"
            }

        }

    },
    "subcategory2" : {
        "group" : {
            "subgroup" :{
                "name" : "Jason Lengstorf",
                "age" : "24","gender" : "male",
                "height" : "6.3",
                "weight" : "164lbs"
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Tip: 1) Get the raw data from your database 2) Parse that array the way you need 3) Convert that prepared array to JSON

Comment: Getting and the data seems to be near impossible for me. I'm trying every tutorial out there and I can't get it to populate more than one cell from one column.

`$profileQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usr";` than
`$profileData = $PDOconn->query($profileQuery);`
`while ($row = $profileData->fetchAll()){` `echo $row;}`

Can't figure out what i'm doing wrong before I encode to JSON.
@Yang

Comment: Change `fetchAll()` to `fetch()`. At the moment you are fetching an array of all the row data into `$row` but your code is written to process it row by row. You still won't be able to `echo $row;` as it's an array but you can use e.g. `print_r($row);` or `var_dump($row);`. Hopefully that will help lead you to a solution.